# Saving an array type data in elastic search and searching by range for an ID

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

How to add an array type JSON in Elastic Search for an ID.
So for `/documentStoreIndex/notesType/1001`

```
{
  “index”: 0,
  “time”:1590652925925,
  “chracter”:“H”
},
{
  “index”: 1,
  “time”:1590652925925,
  “chracter”:“I”
}
```

Later on, I want to do a search

1) “Get me time for index 1 for id 1001”

2) “Get me time array from index 0 to 1 for id 1001"

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to store array using [nested type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html)

**Mapping:**

```
PUT index92
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "field1":{
        "type": "nested"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Query:** To access nested type , [nested query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html) is needed

1. Find  doc with index 1

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "_id": {
              "value": "1000"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "inner_hits": {  --> returns matched nested objects
              "_source": "field1.time"--> select fields to show.
            }, 
            "path": "field1",
            "query": {
              "term": {
                "field1.index": {
                  "value": 1
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

2. Get index from range 0-1

```
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "_id": {
              "value": "XQxiWnIBonxtIN2b07x2"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "inner_hits": {
              "_source": "field1.time"
            }, 
            "path": "field1",
            "query": {
              "range": {
                "field1.index": {
                  "gte": 0,
                  "lte": 1
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Result:** Innert_hits specified in query retuns matching nested documents

```
"hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "index92",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "XQxiWnIBonxtIN2b07x2",
        "_score" : 2.0,
        "_source" : {
          "field1" : [
            {
              "index" : 0,
              "time" : 1590652925925,
              "chracter" : "H"
            },
            {
              "index" : 1,
              "time" : 1590652925925,
              "chracter" : "I"
            }
          ]
        },
        "inner_hits" : {
          "field1" : {
            "hits" : {
              "total" : {
                "value" : 2,
                "relation" : "eq"
              },
              "max_score" : 1.0,
              "hits" : [
                {
                  "_index" : "index92",
                  "_type" : "_doc",
                  "_id" : "XQxiWnIBonxtIN2b07x2",
                  "_nested" : {
                    "field" : "field1",
                    "offset" : 0
                  },
                  "_score" : 1.0,
                  "_source" : {
                    "time" : 1590652925925
                  }
                },
                {
                  "_index" : "index92",
                  "_type" : "_doc",
                  "_id" : "XQxiWnIBonxtIN2b07x2",
                  "_nested" : {
                    "field" : "field1",
                    "offset" : 1
                  },
                  "_score" : 1.0,
                  "_source" : {
                    "time" : 1590652925925
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: How the following is getting inserted in the PUT call ?
“index”: 0,
  “time”:1590652925925,
  “chracter”:“H”

Comment: @SubrataSaha it is added as an array. In mapping field is defined as "nested" POST index-name/_doc
{
  
  "field":"",
  .....
  "field1":[
      {
        "index": 0,
        "time":1590652925925,
        "chracter":"H"    
      },
      {
        "index": 1,
        "time":1590652925925,
        "chracter":"I"
      }
    ]
  
}